# Determine type of result of expression involving template type parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Using c++11:

I'd like to declare a type that is the result of subtracting two template parameter type values.

How can I encode this in my template?

Example:

```
template<typename T>
class C {
    typedef T member_t;
    typedef TYPE_OF_RESULT_OF( T - T ) member_diff_t;
};
```

What would be the replacement for "TYPE_OF_RESULT_OF( T - T )" in the above?

I am expecting to compute a signed difference from any arithmetic type. So I suppose I could use as_signed(T). But it seems more correct to ask the compiler, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple solution would be this:

```
#include <type_traits>

using member_diff_t = typename std::decay<
    decltype(std::declval<T>() - std::declval<T>())>::type;
```

The `decay` makes sure that you get the naked type, with references stripped, in case the operation returns a reference.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'm getting an error on the second typename, but that may be a clang++ issue. I'll upgrade and try again.

Comment: @austinhastings The second `typename` is extraneous.